# How does the mechanics of left-handed scissors differ from right-handed/standard scissors?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, applied-mechanics, friction

So I've read that my right hand with a left-handed scissor "pushes the blades apart" (same with my left hand with right-handed/standard scissors), but I couldn't find out why this happens or how the whole thing works. Also, this is not what I observed when I tested out my left-handed scissors and cut about 3 cm with 2 combinations: left hand with left-handed scissors (expected to push the blades together and cut cleanly, which it did as expected), but when it came to my right hand with the same left-handed scissors, I didn't notice any difference, as if it didn't matter (I might've missed nuances, I'm not sure)

Comment: well -made scissors with good pressure on the blades can work with either hand.  Any slop in the blades will keep them from working.

Answer (score 1):

Scissors operate on the principle of "shearing" action. The slight curvature on the blades means that the point of shearing is where the edges intersect. For a good cutting experience the blades must touch.

[image]
[image]

*Figures 1 and 2 using right-handed scissors in left and right hand.*

In Figure 2, right hand, I'm pulling with my fingers but pushing with the thumb's proximal phalanx. In Figure 2, left hand, my thumb is bent to pull while the fingers are pushing against the edge closest to the camera.

What isn't so obvious is that the scissors relies on having the classic finger loops. A shears with two straight grips will be much more difficult to use as will a scissors with one or both loops broken.

> So I've read that my right hand with a left-handed scissor "pushes the blades apart" ...

This is only true if you use the right-hand grip on a left-hand scissors. Try it again and I think you will find that you are having to modify your grip to get a good cut.